# jQuery mCustomScrollbar "scrollTo" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using a basic setup for `mCustomScrollbar` which is working great except when I call the following:

```
jQuery("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo","top");
```

Nothing happens. There is not error shown in firebug, it just does nothing. Has anyone experienced this before or does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? mine not working too

Comment: It's kinda lame, I finally got it to work. The css was getting loaded and I guess it prevented it to calculate correctly some dimensions.

Answer (score 10):

MCustomScrollbar doesn't provide feature of scrolling to top of the page. However, it does support scrolling to specific element in HTML.

For example, if I have an element with id "logout" which is at top of the page and i need to scroll at top, then write

```
$("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "#logout");
```

Hope you find this useful.

Cheers!

Comment: Update: mCustomScrollbar supports "top". It will find the first element in the container and scroll to it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it simply with calculating the position of my first element and scrolling to that number

Comment: Thanks man! Mine was not working, even selecting the object perfectly. But I tried your approach and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a day. Here's what I got:

Tested and working (2019): `$('.demo-yx').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo',['top',null]);`

From this [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollTo_demo.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a mCustomScrollbar class.....
Here is your answer...

```
$(".scroller-back").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",jQuery("#mcs_container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use like this, it'is working!

```
// set scrollbar
$('.scroll-y').mCustomScrollbar({
  theme: 'minimal-dark'
});

// then set scrollTo
$('.scroll-y').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo', 'bottom');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout( function () {
   $("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo','last');
 }, 100);
```

Use with time out